# In install4j: addInstallerEventListener throws NotSupportedInElevationException

Tags: java, windows-8.1, install4j

In install4j, in a "Run script" action:

- I have "Action elevation type" = "Elevate to maximum available privileges"
- When I call `context.addInstallerEventListener(installerEventListener)`

It works fine in Win7.

But it throws an exception `NotSupportedInElevationException` in **Windows 8**. All the codes in  `public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent event) {}` are not executed when the user cancels the installation.

The user account (that executes the installer) in 2 cases Win7 and Win8 are administrators.

Is this a problem of `install4j` in Windows 8 ?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that in your Windows 7 case, UAC is disabled, so no elevated helper process is started.

You have to execute context.addInstallerEventListener in unelevated code. You can call

```
context.runUnelevated(new RemoteCallable() {
    public Serializable execute() {
        context.addInstallerEventListener(new InstallerEventListener() {
            public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent installerEvent) {
                // TODO
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
});
```

in elevated code.

Comment: Put context.addInstallerEventListener() in the runUnelevated, the exception NotSupportedInElevationException is not appeared anymore. But I want to start some Windows services in  public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent installerEvent) {//Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fileBat)}, it seems that it does nothing. In fileBat, I have some line commands like: net start "serviceName"

Comment: Then you have to register the listener in unelevated code and use context.runElevated to start the Windows services.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Ingo for your prompt helps. The solution for me is:

1. Set the "Action elevation type" of RunScript action to "Do not Elevate".
2. Call normally `addInstallerEventListener` (not in unElevated).
3. Restart some services in runElevated method.

> ```
> public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent installerEvent) {
>       context.runElevated(new RemoteCallable() {
>           @Override
>           public Serializable execute() {
>               Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(startServicesBatchFile);
>               process.waitFor();
>           }
>       }, true);
>   }
> ```

Important: the restart services must be synchronized, so the install4j VM have to wait for the end of this process before being killed.